# Loading a text file as a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to load a tab and or whitespace delimited text file into a two dimensional array.  The file looks something like this:

```
1 -3 4
4 -3 7
8 -1 10
```

I have access to a piece of code that suggests it is permissible to do something such as the following:

```
int nums[][] = {
    #include "matrix.txt"
};
```

However, whenever I try to compile this code I am obtaining the error:

```
$ gcc hangserver.c 
hangserver.c:10:5: error: array type has incomplete element type
In file included from hangserver.c:11:0:
matrix.txt:1:5: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
$
```

I know there are less-elegant ways to load this file into an array, however out of pure curiosity I would like to know if it is possible to implement the methodology shown above. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: `int nums[][]` isn't valid. The maximum of flexibility you can have is `int nums[][<some integer>]`.

Comment: If you're sure not needing to read the file at runtime, and the file's contents is correctly formatted you should be able to do so (don't try to solve an assignment in a _clever_ way) ...

Comment: The `#include` directive simply places the referenced file into that source file when it's compiled. You could cut+paste the contents of `matrix.txt` into `hangserver.c` and figure the syntax errors out from there.

Comment: _'I know there are less-elegant ways to load this file into an array'_ Elaborate on that, if you want to receive a serious answer!

Comment: I find alk's comment to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a comma after every number and every row has to be inside a `{}`:

```
{ 1, -3, 4 },
{ 4, -3, 7 },
{ 8, -1, 10 }
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for your responses.  I also needed to bound the array as described by alk.

Answer (score 2):

There is a conceptual problem in your approach.

If for example you had

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```

How should the compiler know you want a 3x2 or 2x3 or a 1x6 or a 6x1 array?

So it needs to know the number of columns in advance.

For the example above, this

```
int matrix [][3] = {
#  include "data.txt"
};
```

would do, as well a this:

```
int matrix [][2] = {
#  include "data.txt"
};
```

and this:

```
int matrix [][1] = {
#  include "data.txt"
};
```

and this:

```
int matrix [][6] = {
#  include "data.txt"
};
```

Although you get a compiler warning about missing braces, as (for the 1<sup>st</sup> case) above `data.txt` really should look like:

```
{1, 2, 3,},{4, 5, 6,},
```

(The trailing `,`s are optional.)

---

To fully steer this via files from the outside do:

```
int matrix[][
#  include "colums.txt"
] = {
#  include "data.txt"
};
```

Here the content of `columns.txt` would just be an integer describing the intended number of columns the data from `data.txt` shall be broken down to.

Comment: Ouch, that doesn't feel right to give such recommendation! Seriously! (though its technically correct of course) ...

Comment: @g-makulik: The OP asked for, so let's discuss it.

Comment: Let's discuss as soon the OP's wakes up to clarify a bit more about his real intend ;). It might be OK if a solution's input is somehow generated in this way in a bigger system, or just for testing purposes.

Comment: @g-makulik: I love automated configuration, builds and testing.

Answer (score 1):

The line expands into:

```
int nums[][] = {
    1 -3 4
    4 -3 7
    8 -1 10
     };
```

which is not acceptable C and C++ syntax. Try with changing the matrix.txt file into

```
{1, -3, 4},
{4, -3, 7},
{8, -1, 10}
```